# How can I externalize my logout function?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm building a login portal, and the container the portal is in will be cleared and refilled with ajax.  My test page looks like this:

```
<input type="button" id="logoutButton" onClick="Logout()" value="Logout"/>
<form id="loginForm">
    Username: <input type="text" id="username"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" id="password"><br>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    Login status: <div id="loginStatus">No login submitted</div>
    Logout status: <div id="logoutStatus">No logout atttempted</div>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
<script src="javascripts/logout.js"></script>
```

This is logout.js:

```
    function Logout() 
        {
        var logoutRequest = $.ajax(
            {
            url: "/api/LogOut",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json"
            }
        }

        logoutRequest.done(function( response ) 
        {
            $('#logoutStatus').text('Error: ' + response.error + ', Message: ' + response.message);
        });

        logoutRequest.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) 
        {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    });
```

I had this working when it was previously internal (alongside the login script), but I'm not terribly clear on the syntax when it comes to calling it externally.  I've spent the morning looking over various examples on the web, but most examples I find are only related to basic strings.

How can I make Logout() work outside of the main html page?

Comment: Sorry can you clarify your question, what do you want to call externally

Comment: This website apparently cut off the top of the code I tried to post... So, function Logout() is supposed to run when the logout button is clicked.  I am asking how I can get the script to work.

Comment: Just put `<script src="javascripts/logout.js"></script>` inside of `<head></head>` tags in the main page.

Comment: I had tried that previously.  Another post on this site suggested placing a similar script at the bottom of that user's webpage, and this was because they thought it was loading before the page itself was ready, and therefor not being read properly... Though it honestly doesn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script tag in the html is valid. It looks like your brackets are wrong. Try this.

```
function Logout() {
    var logoutRequest = $.ajax({
        url: "/api/LogOut",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json"
    });

    logoutRequest.done(function( response ) {
        $('#logoutStatus').text('Error: ' + response.error + ', Message: ' + response.message);
    });

    logoutRequest.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
}
```

Comment: Excuse me while I bang my head on the desk... Your edit is correct.  The console didn't even see that.

Comment: I would recommend a good IDE, or even a linter, to catch syntax errors :)